# What is the relation between vi, nvi and vim?

Tags: history-of, original-vi, nvi

On some unixes sometime I found a command named `nvi`. It was a vi-like editor, without much of its functionality. Maybe it was a fork of the old `vi`?

Anyways, which `vi` versions are a fork of the others, and which are independent developments? Do they have a "family tree", similar to the unixes?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

From `nvi(1)`:

```
HISTORY
    The ex editor first appeared in 1BSD.  The nex/nvi replacements for the
    ex/vi editor first appeared in 4.4BSD.
```

Some background, from memory, so I hope got the details correct:

In the beginning, UNIX was free. Everyone could request a copy from Ken, and he
would send you a tape with the source (allegedly with the text "love, Ken" on
them). The terms "free software" or "open source" didn't exist yet, but for all
intents and purposes it was "open source".

The reason for this was because UNIX was developed at Bell labs. Bell labs
is part of AT&T which, at the time, had an effective monopoly on telephony. As
part of an agreement with the U.S. government, it was agreed that AT&T was *not*
allowed to enter other fields of businesses (such as computers).

Somewhere along the way this changed, and UNIX became proprietary software. As a
result, BSD (which stems from UNIX) *also* became proprietary software. `vi` was
written as part of BSD, so it also became proprietary.

This is why in the late '80s to early '90s some "vi clones" appeared, such as `stevie` (later the basis for `vim`) and `nvi`.

In the early '90s, people wanted a free BSD system, so `nvi` was created for
4.4BSD-lite (lite meaning, not encumbered by AT&T code), so `nvi` was created as
a "bug-for-bug compatible" replacement for the encumbered `vi`. It has all of the `vi` features, but not the more advanced features you might find in `vim`.

FreeBSD & NetBSD both descend from 4.4BSD-Lite (and OpenBSD & DragonflyBSD
descend from NetBSD and FreeBSD, respectively), which is why they ship with
`nvi` installed by default.

Unlike Linux, BSD systems have a single "base" system of which `nvi` is part
of, so there are *really* 4+ versions of `nvi`. But in reality the changes are
small to non-existent, the BSD projects exchange code, so most bugfixes and
enhancements are shared (but perhaps not all?). I believe FreeBSD added multibyte support a few years ago, for example.

The `vim` story is more boring: Bram was running on Amiga, wanted to run `vi`, but couldn't find a `vi` for Amiga. So he took the `stevie` code, ported it to Amiga, and continued to improved it further. This is why you can still find many Amiga-related notes in the docs even today.

In the meanwhile, UNIX is "free" once more, and you can run
[original `vi`](http://ex-vi.cvs.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Wikipedia claims nvi is based on elvis which shipped with the original 386BSD, and was an effort to make a more purely vi-compatible version. Is this correct?

Comment: `nvi` is missing some features of "original `vi`". For example, Lisp mode (`set lisp`) is not implemented in `nvi`.

Answer (score 5):

The roots of the family trees of vi clones seem to be:

- 1977: ["Traditional vi"](http://ex-vi.sourceforge.net/), Bill Joy's original source, ported and free to use since 2002.
- 1985: [microEmacs](http://www.jamesie.de/microemacs/index.en.html), from which the vi-alike ["vile"](https://invisible-island.net/vile/) was developed.
- 1987: [stevie](https://timthompson.com/tjt/stevie/), from which [vim](https://www.vim.org/) and [xvi](https://martinwguy.github.io/xvi/) were developed.
- 1990: [elvis](http://elvis.the-little-red-haired-girl.org/), from which [nvi](https://sites.google.com/a/bostic.com/keithbostic/vi/) was developed.
- 2000: busybox's "tiny vi"